# How to detect if there is any idle thread in a ThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I created a threadpool with the value of 5. After assigning the tasks to 5 threads, the worker should wait to create the thread until a thread get free in Threadpool. So, how to find, is any thread is free in a threadpool?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: There is a lot of information on the [Javadocs page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, tar. I already looked into it. But after seeing the answer of Rahul Singh and your comment, I understood the Javadocs page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (thread instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor) {
    System.out.println(
        "Pool size is now " +
        ((ThreadPoolExecutor) pool).getActiveCount()
    );
}
```

Taking into Consideration that the name of the ExecutorService  is thread, this provides you the active thread and now you can get the free threads.